# Memoizing AR objects to avoid selects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am working on a project that will query the db about a million times using selects (i.e. find_by_name('bob') or whatever) Instead of hitting the db for all of those selects, if  my dataset is small, I have been thinking about caching the results in a ruby var and just using Array.find to  locate  my object. This would avoid hitting the DB, but I don't nec. like the idea of storing ~15k Ruby objects. Any  other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting blog entry that tells you how to cache query results with memcached and cache_fu: [Coding Block: Caching Active Record Models in Rails 3](http://codingblock.blogspot.com/2011/07/caching-active-record-models-in-rails-3.html).

My advice would be to use something like memcached (as described in the article) or Redis to store your objects, then retrieve them from the cache as needed.

Comment: that's a nice way to cache. I guess I Would still have to use an Array find method on the cached values.

Comment: Ideally I'd make it so that you don't have to do Array.find, because then you really do have 15K Ruby objects. My suggested path is to load up your cache  so you one record value is accessible via one key. So "key_bob" would return the find_by_name("bob") record, and "key_ryan" would find the find_by_name("ryan") record. But if you know your calculation will always look at the same collection of data, then the #cached method in the article might also help.